# unnest a list column after modeling after group_by in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to do linear regression for all groups after `group_by`, save the model coefficients in a list column and then 'expand the list column' using 'unnest'.
Here I use `mtcars` dataset as an example.

Note: I want to use `do' here, because`broom::tidy` does not work for all models.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do(model=lm(mpg~wt+hp, data=.)) %>% 
    mutate(coefs = list(summary(model)$coefficients)) %>% 
    unnest()
```

I want something like this.

```
cyl   term         Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
 4     (Intercept) 36.9083305 2.19079864 16.846975 1.620660e-16
 4     wt         -2.2646936 0.57588924 -3.932516 4.803752e-04
 4     hp          -0.0191217 0.01500073 -1.274718 2.125285e-01
 6.......
 6......
........
```

I got error like below:

```
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

Can anyone help solving this issue? I could not figure it our after trying so many times...

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is.  The `coefficients` in the `list` is of a different structure

Comment: As i said, without the expected output, it is not clear.  Perhaps `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(model=lm(mpg~cyl+hp, data=.)) %>% mutate(coefs = list(summary(model)$coefficients)) %>% select(-model) %>% mutate(coefs = list(map_df(coefs, ~ .x %>%  enframe))) %>% unnest`

Comment: @akrun  I added expected output.

Comment: Try wtih `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(model=lm(mpg~cyl+hp, data=.)) %>% mutate(coefs = list(summary(model)$coefficients)) %>% select(-model) %>% {set_names(.$coefs, .$cyl)} %>% map_df(~ .x %>% as_tibble, .id = 'cyl')`

Comment: @akrun   thank you for your answer. could you put it in answer so that everybody can see it more clearly? also, I change `cyl` to `wt` as independent variable, because `cyl` is the grouping variable.  Thank you.

Comment: Ya, I noticed it.  Thanks for pointing that mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to extract the 'coefs' column (`.$coefs`), set the names of the `list` column with 'cyl' column, loop through the `list` with `map`, convert it to `data.frame`, create a new column based on the row names and use the `.id` to create the 'cyl' column from the `names` of the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   do(model=lm(mpg~ wt + hp, data=.)) %>% 
   mutate(coefs = list(summary(model)$coefficients)) %>%
                 select(-model) %>% 
   {set_names(.$coefs, .$cyl)} %>%
   map_df(~ .x %>% 
               as.data.frame %>%
               rownames_to_column('term'), .id = 'cyl')
# cyl        term    Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#1   4 (Intercept) 45.83607319 4.78693568  9.575243 1.172558e-05
#2   4          wt -5.11506233 1.60247105 -3.191984 1.276524e-02
#3   4          hp -0.09052672 0.04359827 -2.076383 7.151610e-02
#4   6 (Intercept) 32.56630096 5.57482132  5.841676 4.281411e-03
#5   6          wt -3.24294031 1.37365306 -2.360815 7.759393e-02
#6   6          hp -0.02219994 0.02017664 -1.100279 3.329754e-01
#7   8 (Intercept) 26.66393686 3.66217797  7.280896 1.580743e-05
#8   8          wt -2.17626765 0.72094143 -3.018647 1.168393e-02
#9   8          hp -0.01367295 0.01073989 -1.273099 2.292303e-01
```

If we wanted to use `tidy`, then change the contents of `map_df` to

```
       ...                %>%
        map_df(~ .x %>% 
                          broom::tidy(.), .id = 'cyl')
```

---

Also, another option is to `nest` after `group_by` and then apply the `broom::tidy` on the `model` object and then `unnest`

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   nest %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                    summarise(model = list(broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp)))))) %>% 
   unnest %>% 
   unnest
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  could you explain this line?  `{set_names(.$coefs, .$cyl)}` @akrun  why we need the curly bracket?

Comment: @zesla. I added some description.  It is basicaly to create a column with the `.id` argument in `map`.  The curlies are needed as to keep the evaluation for the whole block of code as we are doing multiple things, extracting two columns