# Getting summaries from multiple simple linear regressions in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, tidyverse, purrr

I am performing simple linear regressions on multiple groups from my data set. However, I want extract the summaries from each of these regressions and put them into a master table by organized by group. I can run it like this (and it works):

```
  fit_basic <- rs2_anova %>% #Run multiple simple linear regressions
    group_by(quant_method) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(recoveries ~ treatment, data = .))) 

fit_basic_A <- fit_basic[[1,"model"]] #Remove the model from fit_basic
fit_basic_B <- fit_basic[[1,"model"]] #Remove the model from fit_basic

fit_basic_table_A <- get_regression_table(fit_basic_A) %>%
  select("term", "estimate") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate") %>%
  mutate(quant_method = "A")

fit_basic_table_B <- get_regression_table(fit_basic_A) %>%
  select("term", "estimate") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate") %>%
  mutate(quant_method = "B")

fit_basic_table <- rbind(fit_basic_table_A, fit_basic_table_B)
```

To save myself some lines of code (because I have many more groups than presented here) I thought I could use the map function, but I keep getting stuck at mapping the summary table, which throws an error:

```
fit_basic <- rs2_anova %>% 
  group_by(quant_method) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(recoveries ~ treatment, data = .))) %>%
  mutate(summaries = map(data, get_regression_table(.$model)))

Error in input_checks(model, digits, print) : 
  Only simple linear regression models are supported. Try again using only `lm()` models as appropriate.
```

I also tried something along this line:

```
fit_basic_table <- map(fit_basic$model, 
                           function(x) {
                             p <- get_regression_table(x)
                             cbind(par=rownames(p), p)
                           })
```

But I get a list of dataframes that I can't breakdown into a single dataframe and I have lost my group designations. I have tried:

```
fit_basic_table <- map(fit_basic$model, 
                           function(x) {
                             p <- get_regression_table(x)
                             cbind(par=rownames(p), p)
                           }) %>% 
  map_df(as_tibble, .id = "id")
```

and

```
fit_basic_table <- map(fit_basic$model, 
                           function(x) {
                             p <- get_regression_table(x)
                             cbind(par=rownames(p), p)
                           }) %>% 
  unnest(cols = "id")
```

Any thoughts on how to automate this?

*Random test dataframe:

```
quant_method <- c("A", "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
treatment <- c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y","x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","y")
recoveries <-c("88","86","87","82","85","76","65","55","72","71","98","96","97","92","99","66",
               "55","55","62","61")
rs2_anova <- data.frame(quant_method, treatment, recoveries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `tidyverse` and `broom` packages. It is slightly different from the `purrr` method you were attempting, but I think the result shows the terms that you were interested in extracting from the lm object (*i.e.*, term and estimate).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

#Added the stringsAsFactors argument = F to avoid an error in the lm model
rs2_anova <- data.frame(quant_method, 
                        treatment, 
                        recoveries,
                        stringsAsFactors = F)

fit_basic <- rs2_anova %>% 
  #Group by quant_method column
  group_by(quant_method) %>%
  #do the linear models by grouping var
  do(model = lm(recoveries ~ treatment, data = .)) %>%
  #tidy lm object and order it as tibble
  tidy(model)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I run the do(model = lm(recoveries ~ treatment, data = .)) line I get an error that Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'recoveries' not found

Comment: I ran the code from scratch and it worked. You could check if there is indeed a column named 'recoveries' in your 'rs2_anova' object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [unnest a list column after modeling after group_by in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455273/unnest-a-list-column-after-modeling-after-group-by-in-r)

and modified it to:

```
fit_cec <- rs2_anova %>% 
  group_by(quant_method) %>%
  nest %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                      summarise(model = list(broom::tidy(lm(recoveries ~ treatment)))))) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  unnest(model)
```

or to get all estimates, predictions and summaries (https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups). This also works nicely:

```
fit_cec <- rs2_anova %>% 
  group_by(quant_method) %>%
  nest %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(loss_abs_BC_2 ~ cec, data = .)),
         parameters = map(fit, tidy), #provides estimate table for slope and y-intercept with std.error and estimate p-values
         summary = map(fit, broom::glance), #provides R2, adj.R2, sigma, and model p-value
         predictions = map(fit, augment)) %>% #provides fitted values with residuals and errors
  unnest(parameters) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = c(estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value)) %>%
  unnest(summary) %>%
  unnest(predictions)
```